# What is the proper way to load dependencies in a controller super class of an AngularJS application?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I am building an AngularJS application that provides basic CRUD features. That app is built using TypeScript to take advantage of types and classes. I have a base controller that needs access to several AngularJS dependencies. Originally, I injected the dependencies as follows

**File: base-controller.ts**

```
class BaseController {
    private $location;
    private $routeParams;
    constructor($location, $routeParams) {
        /* Manually inject dependencies */
        this.$location = $injector.get('$location');
        this.$routeParams = $injector.get('$routeParams ');
    }
}
```

**File: list-controller.ts**

```
class WorkRequestListController extends BaseController {
    /* Write code to override base controller or implement local methods */
}

angular.module('app.workRequests')
    .controller('WorkRequestListController', ['$location', '$routeParams',
        ($location, $routeParams) => new WorkRequestListController($location, $routeParams)
]);
```

This solution works, but requires my subclass to be aware of the dependencies required by my base class. If I ever need another dependency in my base class, I would have to change every subclass and the statement which instantiates the controller. To fix these issues, I now simply pass $injector into my base class as follows:

**File: base-controller.ts**

```
class BaseController {
    private $location;
    private $routeParams;
    constructor($injector) {
        /* Load dependencies */
        this.$location = $injector.get('$location');
        this.$routeParams = $injector.get('$routeParams');
    }
}
```

**File: list-controller.ts**

```
class WorkRequestListController extends BaseController {
    /* Write code to override base controller or implement local methods */
}

angular.module('app.workRequests')
    .controller('WorkRequestListController', ['$injector',
        ($injector) => new WorkRequestListController($injector)
]);
```

**Here's my question: Is this the correct way to load dependencies in a super class without forcing the subclass or other code to be aware of the dependencies?**

Answer (score 2):

> Is this the correct way to load dependencies in a super class without forcing the subclass or other code to be aware of the dependencies?

This is a way. Angular doesn't recommend *inheritance* in controllers. It prefers *composistion*. The common functionality should go in a *service*/*factory* that gets injected into your controllers.

Comment: We chose inheritance for controllers because we have base behavior that we want all controllers to implement and we want an easy way to override or extend the functionality in specific controllers. We use services to wrap our API calls, directives for components, and a few filters.

Comment: There isn't a *recommended* pattern here. But i've done the exact same thing as you are doing in my projects (for web services)

Answer (score 2):

There's actually a really simple way to implement a base controller using the $controller service. I wrote a [blog post](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2014/03/25/AngularJS-A-better-way-to-implement-a-base-controller.aspx) about it recently, here's the code snippet showing how it works:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('Diary')

// base controller containing common functions for add/edit controllers
.controller('Diary.BaseAddEditController',
    ['$scope', 'DiaryService',
    function ($scope, DiaryService) {
        $scope.diaryEntry = {};

        $scope.saveDiaryEntry = function () {
            DiaryService.SaveDiaryEntry($scope.diaryEntry);
        };

        // add any other shared functionality here.
    }])

.controller('Diary.AddDiaryController',
    ['$scope', '$controller',
    function ($scope, $controller) {
        // instantiate base controller
        $controller('Diary.BaseAddEditController', { $scope: $scope });
    }])

.controller('Diary.EditDiaryController',
    ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'DiaryService', '$controller',
    function ($scope, $routeParams, DiaryService, $controller) {
        // instantiate base controller
        $controller('Diary.BaseAddEditController', { $scope: $scope });

        DiaryService.GetDiaryEntry($routeParams.id).success(function (data) {
            $scope.diaryEntry = data;
        });
    }]);
```